# Spring security: authentication context available from controller but not from service layer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am adding authentication to my Spring MVC HTTP API.

I have setup a trivial authentication: the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` HTTP header contains the username.

I am using `@PreAuthorize` to do security checks.
Everything works when security is implemented at the controller layer.
However, when I try to add `@PreAuthorize(...)` at the service layer,
it fails with `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`.
It's like the security context is lost when calling the service.

The `TokenAuthentication.kt` file contains the whole auth process:

```kotlin
class TokenAuthentication(
    private val user: User,
    private val token: String,
): Authentication {
    override fun getName(): String = user.id

    override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> = mutableListOf()

    override fun getCredentials(): Any = token

    override fun getDetails(): Any = user

    override fun getPrincipal(): Any = user.id

    override fun isAuthenticated(): Boolean = true

    override fun setAuthenticated(isAuthenticated: Boolean) {
    }
}

class TokenAuthenticationFilter(
    private val userService: UserService,
): OncePerRequestFilter() {
    private fun getAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest): Authentication? {
        val auth = request.getHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN") ?: return null

        val user: User
        try {
            user = userService.get(auth)
        } catch (_: NoSuchElementException) {
            return null
        }

        return TokenAuthentication(user, auth)
    }

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain,
    ) {
        val auth = getAuthentication(request)
        println("AUTHENTICATED WITH USER: ${auth?.name}")
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = auth
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = null
    }
}
```

The `Configuration.kt` configures Spring security to enable `@PreAuthorize`:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
)
class WebSecurityConfiguration(
    private val userService: UserService,
): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        if (http == null)
            return

        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)

        http
            .addFilterBefore(
                TokenAuthenticationFilter(userService),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java,
            )
    }
}
```

The `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(...)` is a failed attempt to solve my problem.

Working code (`@PreAuthorize` at controller layer):

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController(
    private val userMapper: UserMapper,
    private val userService: UserService,
    ...
) {
    @GetMapping("/{uid}")
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.name == #uid")
    fun getUser(@PathVariable uid: String): ResponseEntity<UserDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(userMapper.toDto(userService.get(uid)))
}
```

Non-working code (`@PreAuthorize` at service layer):

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService(private val repository: UserRepository) {
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.name == #id")
    fun get(id: String): User {
        println("USER SERVICE THREAD: ${Thread.currentThread().getId()}")
        println("Security: ${SecurityContextHolder.getContext()}")
        println("Security: ${SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication}")
        println("Security: ${SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication?.name}")
        return repository.findByIdOrNull(id)
            ?: throw NoSuchElementException("user not found: $id")
    }
}
```

How do I make it so `@PreAuthorize` works from the service layer?

Thank you

Logs when `@PreAuthorize` is at the controller layer:

```
2022-08-03 10:48:04.084  INFO 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-03 10:48:04.085  INFO 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-03 10:48:04.085 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-08-03 10:48:04.085 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-08-03 10:48:04.085 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-08-03 10:48:04.090 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@7bd3e67d
2022-08-03 10:48:04.093 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@ddffdcd
2022-08-03 10:48:04.094 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='true': request parameters and headers will be shown which may lead to unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-08-03 10:48:04.094  INFO 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2022-08-03 10:48:04.141 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /users/foo
2022-08-03 10:48:04.149 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.157 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
USER SERVICE THREAD: 117
Security: SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
Security: null
Security: null
2022-08-03 10:48:04.256 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2022-08-03 10:48:04.257 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(2065262541<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-08-03 10:48:04.268 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1452472521 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@2c090939] read-only
2022-08-03 10:48:04.276 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@4acfeef6]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.469 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2022-08-03 10:48:04.470 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(2065262541<open>)]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.475 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1452472521 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@2c090939]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.476 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2065262541<open>)] after transaction
AUTHENTICATED WITH USER: foo
THREAD ID: 117
2022-08-03 10:48:04.494 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /users/foo
2022-08-03 10:48:04.508 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/users/foo", parameters={}
2022-08-03 10:48:04.545 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.foo.controller.UserController#getUser(String)
2022-08-03 10:48:04.549 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-08-03 10:48:04.660 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.foo.controller.UserController.getUser(java.lang.String); target is of class [org.foo.controller.UserController] with attributes [[authorize: 'authentication.name == #uid', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
USER SERVICE THREAD: 117
Security: SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=org.foo.security.TokenAuthentication@342a2d68]
Security: org.foo.security.TokenAuthentication@342a2d68
Security: foo
2022-08-03 10:48:04.671 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1531969803<open>)] for JPA transaction
2022-08-03 10:48:04.671 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2022-08-03 10:48:04.671 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@977246828 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@2c090939] read-only
2022-08-03 10:48:04.671 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@5f1bb12e]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.674 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2022-08-03 10:48:04.675 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1531969803<open>)]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.677 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@977246828 wrapping org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@2c090939]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.677 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2022-08-03 10:48:04.762 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.774 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [UserDto(id=foo, mail=foo@example.com)]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.797 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=org.foo.security.TokenAuthentication@342a2d68] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4643bb4]
2022-08-03 10:48:04.801 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-08-03 10:48:04.802 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-08-03 10:48:04.803 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:48:04.803 DEBUG 12179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Logs when `@PreAuthorize` is at the service layer:

```
2022-08-03 10:35:44.242  INFO 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-03 10:35:44.243  INFO 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-03 10:35:44.244 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-08-03 10:35:44.245 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-08-03 10:35:44.245 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-08-03 10:35:44.253 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@689e0f14
2022-08-03 10:35:44.255 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@3ad0d92
2022-08-03 10:35:44.255 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='true': request parameters and headers will be shown which may lead to unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-08-03 10:35:44.255  INFO 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
2022-08-03 10:35:44.293 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /users/foo
2022-08-03 10:35:44.307 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-08-03 10:35:44.311 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.330 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.330 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-08-03 10:35:44.345 ERROR 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:336) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.foo.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$15f563de.get(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.foo.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter.getAuthentication(TokenAuthentication.kt:50) ~[main/:na]
    at org.foo.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(TokenAuthentication.kt:63) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2022-08-03 10:35:44.357 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2022-08-03 10:35:44.358 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-08-03 10:35:44.358 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.367 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.370 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2022-08-03 10:35:44.377 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-08-03 10:35:44.412 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2022-08-03 10:35:44.414 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-08-03 10:35:44.508 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-08-03 10:35:44.511 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Wed Aug 03 10:35:44 CEST 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, trace=org.springf (truncated)...]
2022-08-03 10:35:44.751 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.764 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-08-03 10:35:44.766 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
2022-08-03 10:35:44.773 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2022-08-03 10:35:44.773 DEBUG 11476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: can i ask you why you are building some sort of custom authentication (which is bad practice since there are standards for authentication that should be followed) instead of using one of the authentication ways provided by spring security?

Comment: The external auth server I will use will provide the user a token and I will request the auth server to validate and parse it (to get a username).

Comment: that is still not an answer to my question. Spring security has support for handling all kinds of tokens, so again, why are you building something custom and not using the built in support in spring security and customize it to your needs?

Comment: for instance https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ that is using the header you have specified